# Angular2 binding throws an error "Expression has changed after it was checked"

Tags: html, angular2-directives, angular2-components

As i having parent and child component as follows,

**Child Component (RWTaxComponent)**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'rw-tax',
    templateUrl: 'rw.tax.component.html'
})
export class RWTaxComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() hsn: string = '';
    @Input() srno: string = '';
    @Input() taxPercent: number;
    @Output() taxPercentChange: any = new EventEmitter();
    constructor(
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
     }

    ngOnChanges(event) {
        console.log('HSN:: '+this.hsn);
        console.log('SRNO:: '+this.srno);
        if (this.hsn && this.srno) {
            // Doing my logic here to find taxPercent
            this.taxPercentChange.emit(this.taxPercent);
        }
    }}
```

Child component template (**rw.tax.component.html**) is,

```
<p>{{taxPercent | number:'1.2-2'}}</p>
```

And i invoked the above child component in my parent component as follows,

```
<rw-tax [(hsn)]="lineItem.hsn" [(srno)]="lineItem.srno" [(taxPercent)]="lineItem.taxPercent"></rw-tax>
```

I want to change taxpercent whenever **hsn/srno** is changed, these hsn/srno is not changed in `RWTaxComponent` itself, it is changed by parent component.

So i used `ngOnChanges()` event to detect that hsn/srno is changed and it getting invoked when ever i change hsn and srno in my parent component.
But the problem is after doing my logic to find taxpercent am trying to update the value in parent component by `this.taxPercentChange.emit(this.taxPercent);` and getting error *"Expression has changed after it was checked"*

Am i wrongly understood the Angular2 lifecycle ?

Please suggest a right way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when there is a change in input of the component and on that change if we are trying to change or emit any property.

Solution 1:
try promises resolve the changes and in then block emit the output event.

Solution 2 : (may not work)
Try setTimeout method on emitting the value